# Can you filter an indexed event parameters?

Tags: ethereumjs, logs, filters, bloom-filter

Can you filter an indexed event parameters?

Does indexing make filtering more efficient or does indexing make filtering possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indexing event variables is used for better filtering. indexed values are saved as topics that can be filtered from the start of the RPC call. these values are stored in topics the same way as the name and definition of the event.

Comment: so can I filter unindexed parameters in etherjs?

Comment: @YulePale please be aware that ethereum indexing method is not the same as BTREE method in databases. In databases you have a binary tree where the lookup takes O(log(n)) . Here in Ethereum bloom filter is used so it is not clear if it is faster than btree, you need to investiage on this. Apparently it scans blocks with bloom filter sequentially.

Comment: @YulePale no, you can't scan unindexed parameters, you have to scan them and build your own DB. For example Uniswap v2 has about 50 million swap events since its release in June 2020 , and I am pretty sure a btree scan would be faster than using `Geth`.